# AngularJs with bs-datepicker - setting 'data-min-date' to 'tomorrow'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-strap

I am working with AngularJs, using the `bs-datepicker` widget from [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) and have a form where the minimum date allowed is `'tomorrow'`. Seeing as `data-min-date` can be set to `'today`', I had hoped that it would be as easy as changing the value to `'tomorrow'`. Alas, that is not the case.

Given that I'm not super confident with AngularJS to begin with, I'm hoping for some guidance here.

My field currently looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="startDateValidation" class="form-control"
       ng-model="developer.form.startDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" data-min-date="today"
       data-date-format="MM/dd/yyyy" bs-datepicker required>
```

I have tried creating a date in my controller:

```
self.tomorrow = new Date();
self.tomorrow.setDate(self.tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
```

And then tried each of the following:

```
data-min-date="developer.tomorrow"
data-min-date="{developer.tomorrow}"
data-min-date="{{developer.tomorrow}}"
```

As is probably clear, I'm not sure how angular works, so I'm just bashing around in the dark here. Anyone with any experience would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to set a property on your controller rather than on your controller's `$scope`.

try

```
$scope.tomorrow = new Date();
$scope.tomorrow.setDate($scope.tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
```

Remember you'll have to inject `$scope`!

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: Hmm. No luck with that. I'll also note that other variables set at that level (or in that way) appear to be available within the template

Comment: Working now. `$scope` solved it once I updated the template to use `data-min-date="{{tomorrow}}"` - I also had to re-set the time component to 0: `tomorrow.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Sweet! Glad you got it figured out!